# Matplotlib chop off plot title text

Tags: matplotlib, plot, text

I am using Python and Matlotlib to draw some plots but unfortunately the plot title text is cut off by the window size. even the plt.tight_layout() can't fix the problem. The text is shown correctly by manually increasing the window width.
here' s a picture with the plot problem [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt2Ho.png)
Any suggestions to have the code to fix it automatically without manually resizing window width?
Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

plot title text is shown cut off. it seems that the windows width is not set automatically to include all the text.

Comment: Please post code as text, never as an image.  If the text is much too long, you need to choose a smaller font size, abbreviate the title and/or put the title on multiple lines (`ax.set_title("extremely very\nlong title")`).  Note that `plt.tight_layout()` never changes the figure width nor the font sizes. It only changes the spacing around and between the subplots.  Matplotlib can't know whether a larger window would be acceptable.